# Finding variance of an integrable rndom variable

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be an integrable r.v with density $f(x) $ and $\mu = \mathbb{E} \{ X \} $. I want to show that $Var(X) = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} (x - \mu)^2 f(x) dx $

I know $Var(X) = \mathbb{E} \{ (X - \mathbb{E} (X) )^2 \} $ and I have that if $h$ is measurable function and positive then

$$ \mathbb{ E } \{ h(X) \} = \int h(x) P_X(dx) $$

where $P_X$ is distribution of $X$.

So with this I can just let $h(x) = (x-\mu)^2 \geq 0 $, but how can I make this look into the integral that I want to find ?

Comment: Note: $\mu = \mathbb{E}(X)$ and is in particular a *constant*.  Try expanding $(x-\mu)^2$ and separating the integral over the summands using the property that $\mathbb{E}$ and $\int$ are *linear* operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I make this look into the integral that I want to find ?

Since the density function is the derivative of a continuous distribution, $f(x) = \frac{P_X(\operatorname d x)}{\operatorname d x}$

Then, $\int_\Bbb R h(x) \; P_X(\operatorname d x) = \int_\Bbb R h(x)\; f(x) \;\operatorname d x$

So just let $h(x) = (x-\mu)^2$ and you're done.

Comment: Since In the formula given the integral has no limits of integration, do I just have to assume that it is an integral from $- \infty $ to $\infty $ ?

Comment: Yes.  You do. @easy